# (Scala) Updating a leaf in a json tree

Tags: json, scala

I have a Json block like below:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "my_filter_123": {
            "type":       "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "foxes_123.txt"
        },
        "my_filter_453": {
            "type":       "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "foxes_456.txt"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer_abc": {
            "type":         "custom",
            "tokenizer":    "standard",
            "filter":       [ "lowercase",
                            "my_filter_123"]
        },
        "my_analyzer_def": {
            "type":         "custom",
            "tokenizer":    "standard",
            "filter":       [ "lowercase",
                            "my_filter_456"]
        }
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to Scala and functional programming and am having difficulty updating immutable objects... ( I know that I can't update it, and that I need to make a modified copy of it)

I am trying to modify the value specified at a leaf where I don't care about nor know the exact path to get there. I have been trying to use the json transform function with update, but it seems to need a known path such as (__ \ "filter" \ "my_filter_123" \ "synonyms_path"). I would ideally like to use recursive paths such as (__ \ "synonyms_path"), but that does not seem to work.

The end result I would like to have is to prepend a directory to the synonyms_path specified like below:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "my_filter_123": {
            "type":       "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms_folder/foxes_123.txt"
        },
        "my_filter_453": {
            "type":       "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms_folder/foxes_456.txt"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer_abc": {
            "type":         "custom",
            "tokenizer":    "standard",
            "filter":       [ "lowercase",
                            "my_filter_123"]
        },
        "my_analyzer_def": {
            "type":         "custom",
            "tokenizer":    "standard",
            "filter":       [ "lowercase",
                            "my_filter_456"]
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance as to what direction I should be looking in would be greatly appreciated. I seem to be banging my head against a wall and I assume that this is really not as hard as I am making it.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit

Most of what I have tried did not get me far so I have deleted it, but here is an example of me trying to get the update functionality to just add a field to a path that I dont know all of the steps on the way there:

```
      val t = (__ \\ "synonyms_path").json.update(
        __.read[JsObject].map{ o => o ++ Json.obj( "newField" -> "test" ) }
      )

      val v = request.body.transform(t)
```

The result of which is:
JsError(List((//synonyms_path,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))

Comment: What code have you tried so far? How are you planning on manipulating the json?  Any specific libraries?